# Помогите с решение маленькой проблемы

Tags: java, android

Помогите, при открытии появляются 2 картинки вместо одной, я нашёл место где это происходит, но не знаю как исправить. Мне нужно чтобы осталось только нижнее изображение с текстом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код, где это происходит:

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity {

private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);
    TextView viewById = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
    String name = user.get("login");
    viewById.setText(name);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    **NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.addHeaderView(header);**
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_framepot) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_popular) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_trends) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_ratings) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {


            } else if (id == R.id.nav_exit) {
                session.setLogin(false);
                db.deleteUsers();
                Intent intent = new Intent(home.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    });

}

     /**
     * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
     * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
     * */


public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

Там где выделено "**" мне нужно чтобы осталось только 2 строка, но без первой не работает. Прошу помощи.

Comment: Проблема решена, спасибо всем тем кто пытался помочь.

Comment: Если вы сами нашли проблему, то можете написать её решение в ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте удалить строчку:

`View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);`

Comment: не получится т.к эта одна из строчек отвечает за вывод `TextView: View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);
    TextView viewById = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView3);`